# android select language (Arabic in Arabic, English in English, French in French)

Tags: android

I am about to build android app in three language (Arabic, English, French)
User can select his language to display the app in desired language.

I need to know, how to display the name of each language in it's language?

check the following image how to display a list of three languages only (Arabic, English, French) in it's native language as show bellow ? is there

[image]

Comment: I saved the strings in... (guess?) arrays.xml - Another choice would be strings.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java (and Android too) has names and translations built in and you can get them via `Locale`

For example

```
Locale[] locales = new Locale[] {
        Locale.getDefault(),
        Locale.FRENCH,
        Locale.CHINESE,
        new Locale("ar", "DZ")
};
for (Locale locale : locales) {
    System.out.println(locale.getDisplayLanguage(locale));
    //                         ^ returns name in  ^ it's own language
}
```

---

```
English
français
中文
العربية
```

prints above and you can use those `String`s as items in a dialog. I suspect that the example in your picture has them hardcoded in xml resources though since "US English" looks custom for example. Note: `Locale.getDefault()` returns the language the device is set to, it's not hardcoded to "English" and you would have to add that via `Locale.US` for example.

Answer (score 0):

For the particular menu you present use default (unqualified) string resources for the menu. The values XML files are UTF-8 so you can put any language in it.